# implement a perfect Logout function using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working for a simple Login app using angular js. Here, I need to implement a logout functionality. I am trying to do it by using javascript which shows a problem as it's only redirecting to loggedout page and not restricting to go back to prevoiusly visited pages.

I heard about sessions. I am new to angular js.

Can anyone help me to implement sessions to get the logout function working perfectly.

Any suggestion/example would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to store (for example in url as returnUrl query string parameter) the current url before the user is redirected to login page.

Comment: @MajoB... here, suppose I am at homepage then the url is showing as "Localhost:8085/Dashboard.html?userId=1&name=Roger&password=1234". then what to do further, please reply.

Comment: Do not store user name in password in url, it is not secure. Your question is very general. There is a lot of examples on internet how to implement authentication in angularjs https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=a6gSVKPeB-riywPmoYLwDw#q=how+to+implement+angularjs+authentication.